# Can anyone help me to solve this circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics, batteries

[image]

Assuming the diode voltage is 0.7V, how to calculate the current flowing through the diode? And how does the earthing function in this circuit?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: FYI - this has now been asked and answered on [EE StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/534659/how-to-calculate-current-flowing-through-this-diode).